# Playing audio through audio tag in a Django application

Tags: python, django, file, audio

How do i use the audio tag of html 5 to play a audio file that has been uploaded in a my django based application.
models.py - [Link](https://github.com/anurag-ks/acoustique/blob/master/music/models.py)
settings.py - [Link](https://github.com/anurag-ks/acoustique/blob/master/main/settings.py)

In my templates i am using the `audio` tag in the following way -

```
    {% for file in audio %}
    <li>
    <h4>{{ file.title }}</h4>
    <div id="name"><a href="{{ file.audio_file }}" target="_blank">{{ file.name }}</a></div>
    <div id="play"><audio src="{{ file.audio_file }}" controls="controls">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio></div>
    </li>
   {% endfor %}
```

But I am not able to play the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your settings, you cannot play the file because:

- `{{ file.audio_file }}` returns value saved in the database, which is *absolute path* to media file, e.g. `http://localhost:8000/Users/test/django_app/media/test.wav`

To solve this, you need to:

1. Edit your `models.py`

   `class AudioFile(models.Model):
       audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to="music")`

   [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) -- A path that will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting to determine the value of the url attribute
2. In your template, use `{{ file.audio_file.url }}` to correctly reference the URL of the uploaded file
3. You may need to delete existing files, because wrong path was saved in the database.